# can I return to the UK by using a one way ticket as I am planning on staying in London

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, legal, one-way

I have four interviews for work lined up and need to get to the UK ASAP but am not sure if it is allowed to enter with only a one way ticket. I am a british citizen and is in possesion of my British passport.

Comment: If you're a british citizen, why on earth wouldn't it be?

Comment: @pnuts I'm starting to see what you meant when you said that it's like there's someone here upvoting like every single question.

Answer (score 10):

> **Can I return to the UK? ... I am a British Citizen**

[Yes](https://www.gov.uk/right-of-abode/overview).

> Having right of abode means you’re allowed to live or work in the UK **without any immigration restrictions**, which means:
>
> you won’t need a visa to come to the UK
>
> there’s no limit on the length of time you can spend in the country
>
> **All British citizens automatically have right of abode in the UK**.

(my emphasis)

So, you don't need a ticket for a later flight out of the UK.

I've entered the UK many times without such a ticket.

---

You write that you are a British **Citizen**. This is different from a British Subject, a British Overseas Citizen and several other types of British national.

- [Types of British Nationality](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality)